# Filter out particular response codes from CustomLog

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I want to prevent all those 408's from showing up in one of my log files. Is there a way to prevent this? I found the syntax for limiting the printing of any particular format string, but not the entire log entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out conditional logging in apache. I am not sure it will work here unless you can filter on the URI.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.htm

Search for Conditional Logging.

Otherwise, look into piped logging. You can pipe your logs into a filter (grep -v " 408 ") before dumping it into a file.

May want to check on any performance hit.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#piped